# Javascript Replace Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Ok, I'm actually trying to replace text.

Basically, I am needing to replace all instances of this:  `|` with a blank string `''`

However, this isn't working:

`langName = langName.replace(/|/g, '');`

Also, would be best if I could also replace all of these instances within the string, with a `''` also:

`"` double quote

`'` single quote

`/` back slash

`\` forward slash

And any other html entity characters.  Arrggg.

Can someone please help me here?  Perhaps it can be turned into a `String.prototype` function so I can use it more than once?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `|` with `\` like:

```
langName = langName.replace(/\|/g, '');
```

**Test Case:**

```
var langName = 'this| is | some string';

langName = langName.replace(/\|/g, '');
alert(langName);
```

**Output:**

```
this is some string
```

The reason why you need to escape `|` is that it is special regex character.

---

Alternatively, you could also use `split` and `join` like this:

```
langName = langName.split('|').join('');
```

Comment: OMG, it's that simple... argg.  Thanks, giving it a try now... lol

Comment: which is faster?  split().join() or replace()?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: I haven't benchmarked them but whenever i can use split and join, i go for them. As for speed, there shouldn't be much difference if the string isn't that huge which is the case mostly :)

Comment: So if the character `|` doesn't exist in the string, split and join won't work will it?  So, I'm guessing that `langName` would return an empty string in that case?

Comment: @Sologhost: It would return string as it is, in our case `this is some string`